# Getting array of values from jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following object:

```
$("input:checkbox:checked")
[
<input class=​"li_checker" type=​"checkbox" category_uid=​"1.3" category_language=​"da">​, 
<input class=​"li_checker" type=​"checkbox" category_uid=​"1.3.1" category_language=​"da">​
]
```

If there is any helper in jQuery which allows me to get value of "category_uid" for all elements and returns it as the another array? Expected result:

```
["1.3", "1.3.1"]
```

Comment: Have you tried the .attr()? http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: @chchrist `.attr()` will only return the attribute value for the first element in the set.

Comment: you can use .each() to loop their .attr()

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
var myArray = $("input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
  return this.getAttribute("category_uid");
}).get();
```

Comment: Important to note that `map` doesn't return an array, it returns a jQuery wrapper *around* an array. You have to use `.get()` to get the actual array.

Comment: That's a nice solution.  My first through was what Russell and bazmegakapa had suggested.

Comment: I used this one since was shortest.

Answer (score 7):

As bpierre suggested, use `.map()`. His answer is correct.

If you need this behavior for different attributes, you might as well write is as a reusable function (“jQuery plugin”):

```
jQuery.fn.pluck = function(attr) {
  return this.map(function() {
    return this.getAttribute(attr);
  }).get();
};

$('input:checkbox:checked').pluck('category_uid'); // ["1.3", "1.3.1"]
```

P.S. `category_uid` is not a valid attribute in HTML. Consider using custom `data-*` attributes instead, e.g. `data-category-uid="foo"`.

Answer (score 5):

Just for the fun of it, a *third* way, this one using [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr#attr2):

```
var categories = [];
$("input:checkbox:checked").attr("category_uid", function(index, value) {
    categories.push(value);
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/otuyi4)

---

**Off-topic**: If you want to have arbitrary, custom attributes on HTML elements, recommend using the `data-` prefix defined by HTML5 ([details](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes)). You can use it now, even if you're not using the HTML5 doctype (this is one of the places where HTML5 is just codifying — and reining in — current practice), and it future-proofs a bit.

Comment: I've just realized that this relies on undocumented behavior (leaving the attribute alone if the function doesn't return anything or returns `undefined`). So I've logged a [ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8770) to document it (or not, of course, if it's not desired behavior).

Comment: @bluszcz: No worries, have fun. (Spain, eh? And I would have though the Czech Republic, from your username...)

Answer (score 1):

```
var myarray=[];
$("input:checkbox:checked").each(function () {
  myarray.push($(this).attr('category_uid'));
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F45vY/)

Comment: i dont think he only needs the checked ones

Comment: He suggested something like that in his question, that's why I used this selector.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
var checked_cats = new Array();
$("input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
   checked_cats.push($(this).attr('category_uid'));
});
```

(not tested)

p.s. saw your tweet.

Comment: And how is this different from my answer posted earlier?

Comment: @bazmegakapa: He uses `new Array()` rather than the more reliable, and more concise, `[]`. ;-)

Comment: older versions of ie will throw an error if you "push" something to an array declared without the "new" keyword ;)

Comment: @gion_13: I don't know what version of IE you're talking about, but `[]` has been correct array literal syntax for donkey's years (like, before JavaScript was handed to the ECMA; eons ago in computing terms). It works on IE6. Fortunately, I don't have (or need) access to earlier versions than that.

Comment: @gion_13: `push` is supported in IE since version 5.5. Even on that version, I haven't found any evidence about the bug you talked about.

Comment: @bazmegakapa - we posted at almost the same time, great minds think alike! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more "pluginy" way to do this:

```
(function($){

    $.fn.getAttributes = function(attribute){
        var result = [];
        $(this).each(function(){
             var a = $(this).attr(attribute);
             if(a)
                 result.push(a);
        });
        return result;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

and then use it as follows :

```
var result = $("input:checkbox:checked").getAttributes("category_uid");
```

Haven't tested it, but it should work just fine.

Comment: With respect: *Very* inefficient, you're repeating calls all over the place (to `$()`, to `attr()`). Bad enough in application code, but plugin code should strive for efficiency. (Also, you forgot to declare your `$` argument, but good form [intending to] use one.)

Comment: T.J. makes very good points. Also, why reinvent the wheel (`.map()`) when jQuery already has such a method?