# Multiple submit buttons on one page but distinguishable (jquery)

Tags: php, jquery, forms, submit

I am trying to write a code that 'stores items for later' - a button that has url of the item as hidden input, on submit it calls a php script that does the storage in a db. I am more into php, very little knowledge of anything object-oriented, but I need to use jquery to call the php script without moving over there

The problem is how to assign the x and y variables when I have multiple forms on one page

I was only able to write the following

```
 $("form").bind('submit',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

      var x =  $("input[type=hidden][name=hidden_url]").val();
      var y =  $("input[type=hidden][name=hidden_title]").val();



   $.ajax({
   url: 'save_storage.php?url='+x+'&tit='+y,
   success: function() {
    alert( "Stored!");
     location.reload();
   }
});
```

});

It works fine if you have something like...

```
<form method="post" action="#">
 <input type="hidden" id="hidden_url"  name="hidden_url" value="<?php echo $sch_link; ?>"/>
 <input type="hidden" id="hidden_title" name="hidden_title" value="<?php echo $sch_tit; ?>"/>
 <input type="submit" id="send-btn"  class="store" value="Store" />
</form>
```

..once on the page, I've got about 50 of them.

These are generated via for-loop I suppose I could use $i as an identifier then but how do I tell jquery to assign the vars only of the form/submit that was actually clicked?

Comment: this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13036676/jquery-get-values-from-inputs-and-create-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to scope finding the hidden fields to look within the current form only. In an event handler, `this` will refer to the form that was being submitted. This will only find inputs matching the given selector within that form.

```
$("form").bind('submit',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var x =  $(this).find("input[type=hidden][name=hidden_url]").val();
  var y =  $(this).find("input[type=hidden][name=hidden_title]").val();

  $.ajax({
    url: 'save_storage.php',
    data: {
      url: x,
      tit: y
    },
    success: function() {
      alert( "Stored!");
      location.reload();
    }
  });
});
```

As @Musa said, it's also better to supply a `data` key to the `$.ajax` call to pass your field values.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your form submit handler, you have access to the form element through the `this` variable. You can use this to give your selector some context when searching for the appropriate inputs to pass through to your AJAX data.

This is how:

```
$("form").bind('submit',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // good practice to store your $(this) object
    var $this = $(this);

    // you don't need to make your selector any more specific than it needs to be
    var x = $this.find('input[name=hidden_url]').val();
    var y = $this.find('input[name=hidden_title]').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'save_storage.php',
        data: {url:x, tit: y},
        success: function() {
            alert( "Stored!");
            location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

Also, IDs need to be unique per page so remove your `id` attribute from your inputs.