# Javascript Dynamic Form Field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am having difficulty with a javascript that I need some help with. I have a form which sends to a php the exact amount of inputs to be filled, now I want to create a preview using jQuery/javascript but how can I catch all the fields dynamically.

**Here is a portion of my form for reference:**

```
<td>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span>
        <input class="form-control" id="task" type="text" name="task" placeholder="Task Title">
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
        </span>
        <input class="form-control"  id="description" type="text" name="description" placeholder="Task Description">
    </div>
</td>
```

So, I added in PHP the name field + the number, this way I can get different names ie: `task1`, `task2`,...etc.

Now what I need to do is get the values using jQuery/javascript.

My thoughts so far is to declare the `var` (variable) inside a `for()` (loop)

```
var task = $('input[name=task]').val();
```

How can I get all values `task1`, `task2`. No one knows how many task fields the user will submit so I need to get the number of fields

Any help direction so I can figure this out

Comment: Give them all the same class, e.g. `class="form-control task"`. Then you can use `$("input.task")` to get them all.

Comment: please check [link](http://jsfiddle.net/tty1nf0/5nd7308L/2/) how can I get all values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

```
var tasks = $('input[name^=task]').val();
$.each(tasks,function(index, value){
   //do something with the value
   alert($(this).val());
});
```

**edit**

```
var tasks = $('input[name^=task]');
$.each(tasks,function(index, value){
   //do something with the value
   $('#Preview').append($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Your solution is brilliant, few lines of code. but how can I print the value for task1, task2, task3?`$('#Preview').text($(this).val());` it does not show me anything

Comment: I have updated my answer. (1) remove the `.val()` from `var tasks =...`. (2) Instead of using `.text()` which will overwrite and only show the last result, use `.append()`. Your updated jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/5nd7308L/10/

Comment: this is awesome, I really thank you very much. For me to understand more, append() lists the result right?

Comment: [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) inserts/adds to the end of the selected element. `$.each()` is what allows it to list all. If you use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) you will just overwrite the selected element on each loop so only the last value will be shown.

Answer (score 2):

**First of all**, you don't need to give your input fields names like `task1, task2, etc` to distinguish among them on the server-side i.e on the PHP. You just need to give all of them a name attribute value like `tasks[]` **And notice the brackets []** so you may have something like the following:

```
<input class="form-control" id="tasks[]" type="text" name="tasks[]" placeholder="Task Title">
...
<input class="form-control" id="tasks[]" type="text" name="tasks[]" placeholder="Task Title">
```

Like that automatically values in those fields will be posted as an array to the PHP and it is going to be received like the following in PHP script:

```
$tasks = $_POST['tasks'];
foreach ($tasks as $task){
   echo $task;
}
```

**Second** By this way you will easily able to collect your inputs data using Javascript inorder to generate the preview by using `getElementsByName` method as follows:

```
function preview(){
      output = "";
      tasks = document.getElementsByName('tasks[]');
      for (i=0; i < tasks.length; i++){
        output += "<b>Title</b>: "+tasks[i].value+"<hr />";
      }
      panel = document.getElementById('panel');
      panel.innerHTML = output;
    }
```

Of course you can expand this solution to any number of fields in your form such as `descriptions[]`.

A javascript DEMO: http://jsbin.com/kiyisi/1/

Answer (score 0):

Q: `now I want to create a preview using jquery/javascript but how can I catch all the fields dinamically`:

If you give them a class, you can get all fields with `each`:

```
$(".className").each(function() {
    do something
```

**Next**, "catch" all fields... I'm assuming you may want the values of these fields too? Check [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13036676/jquery-get-values-from-inputs-and-create-an-array) for details, here is a snippet which loads the **key:value** pairs (*form field name* **:** *value of field*) into a map:

```
var map = {};
$(".activeInput").each(function() {
    map[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
});
```

---

Print all values inside div (Here, I'm assuming you're talking about children values of div):

```
<div>
    <span>Hi</span>
    <span>Hello</span>
    <span>Hi again</span>
</div>

$("div").children().each(function () {
   console.log($(this).text());   
});
```

OR

```
$("div span").each(function () {
   console.log($(this).text());   
});
```

Comment: I also tried yours, but same issue, how can I print all values inside a div? `$('#Preview').text(map.task);`missing the number in front of the word task

Comment: Check this link [http://jsfiddle.net/tty1nf0/5nd7308L/7/](http://jsfiddle.net/tty1nf0/5nd7308L/7/) I am so stuck, and I know it is pretty easy the solution, but no idea how do make it work. The children div, may not be the solution, since I want to preview the values in a div with a unique ID