# jQuery .val() only returning the first value in the form? How to get all values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to perform a simple form validation pre-submit for UX enhancement purposes only. Problem that I am having is that `.val()` is only returning the first form field value and ignoring the rest.

## jQuery

```
        $('#pForm').submit(function(){
            var print = $(".option:checked").val();
            var design = $(".option:checked").val();
            var error = "Please select a design service...";

            if(print == 'p10','p20','p30','p40','p90','p00'
            && design == 'd10','d20','d30','d40','d00') {

               alert(print);
               alert(design);

               return true;

            } else {

               alert(error);
               return false;

            }

        });
```

## HTML (example code)

Each radio is labeled as follows:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="design" class="option" data-number="<?php echo $var ?>" value="d40"/></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="design" class="option" data-number="<?php echo $var ?>" value="d30"/></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="design" class="option" data-number="<?php echo $var ?>" value="d20"/></label>

<label><input type="radio" name="print" class="option" data-number="<?php echo $var ?>" value="p40"/></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="print" class="option" data-number="<?php echo $var ?>" value="p30"/></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="print" class="option" data-number="<?php echo $var ?>" value="p20"/></label>
```

End result is that I do not want the form to submit unless a value is choose from the print radio fields && the design radio fields. If the check fails I want to display an `error` message to the user.

*Some of the code above may be *semi-pseudo* Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: `$(".option:checked").val();` used twice, you should at least use better selector like `$(".option[name="design"]:checked").val()` then just check `.length` of selected object and decide alert user

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/U4Pk3/

Comment: Your jsFiddle set me on the right path! Thank You I made my own before I saw yours.. The syntax is what really get me (?) .. thanks again --> see mine  jsfiddle.net/GtBrF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, now that it's more clear what you're trying to do, then just do this to make sure that there is an item checked in each group:

```
if (!$(".design:checked").length || !$(".print:checked").length) {
   // something is not selected
}
```

Once you ensure that there is a selected value in both, then you can get the value of the first item that is checked with this code:

```
 var print = $(".print:checked").val();
 var design = $(".design:checked").val();
```

Comment: Okay forgive me as I'm learning this... On `.submit` i just want to ensure that a value is checked from the two radio groups.. What exactly is `index, element`? Thanks

Comment: @fabio - I've added a way to check if there is an item checked in each group.  Basically, you just verify that there is at least one item in each jQuery object by checking the `.length` property.  If so, both have a checked item.

Comment: Ok thats awesome so then if they're not checked that just returns no length ( or null) and that means I don't need to check for the actual values. Cool. I'm trying this out now. Thanks :)

Comment: @fabio - if there are no checked items, the jQuery object will have a length of zero.  That's how you check if a jQuery object is empty.  Note, I corrected your code for getting the `print` and `design` values.  You weren't using the right selectors for them.

Comment: || operator  is considered AND in JS? Thats the considered OR in PHP? I thought AND was &&

Comment: @fabio - `||` is the `OR` operator in JS, just like everywhere else.  The logic here is: if either `.design:checked` has zero length OR `.print:checked` has zero length, then something is not selected that should be and you should either stop processing or show an error or both.  It could also have been written `if ($(".design:checked").length != 0 && $(".print:checked").length != 0)`.

Comment: So I can put a nested `if` within this block to get the `length` and if `length == 0` I can display the appropriate error message. Cool! I got it. Thanks

Comment: Ahh I see what you did. You negated by using this `!` at the beginning. Thanks! I get it. Thanks for the thorough explanation!

Comment: I'm getting strange values for length when I alert them to test. For example it says 29 and 30, What exactly is length counting? The value is only 3 chars long .. ex: `p20` what is 30?

Comment: @fabio - Are you doing `$(".option:checked").length`?  That will look at all checked options in the whole page.  You should be doing `$(".print:checked").length` or `$(".design:checked").length`.  `.length` is the number of DOM objects in the jQuery (how many matched the selector).  For further detailed help, you'd have to show me a working page with your HTML and code in it since I don't know exactly what code/HTML you're asking about.

Comment: hey thanks again.. I was really trying to get this going without further help but my efforts have failed. Please take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/GtBrF/   Thanks again :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GtBrF/1/  < revised... jsFiddle is giving a strange error.. Built with django lol

Comment: @fabio - I don't know what logic you're trying to implement.  I'm guessing that `if (design_v || print_v != 0) ` should be `if (design_v  != 0 && print_v != 0)` to ensure that both are non-zero.

Comment: @fabio - I'm sorry, but we aren't here to write code for you.  I've answered multiple questions for you.  Your latest jsFiddle is not set for jQuery (in the left hand panel) so it will never work and there's no `id="pForm"` object anywhere in your HTML so even when you do set it to jQuery, it will never work.  This fixed version works: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/EkvAp/

Comment: sorry i forgot to save and update: http://jsfiddle.net/GtBrF/2/  notice the output?

Comment: @fabio - I'm done now.  I've fixed your problem 3 separate times so far and even given you a working jsFiddle.  You need to either take things from there yourself or post a new separate question.

Answer (score 2):

val() always returns just the value of the first element.
http://api.jquery.com/val/

See this question for a good solution using map:
[Getting array of values from jQuery object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550220/getting-array-of-values-from-jquery-object)

Answer (score -1):

You're close. Try this.

```
if((print == '') || (design == '')) {

       //error 
}
```